# Using F# to calculate triangle

Tags: f#, geometry

I'm trying to write a program to calculate triangles. Can anyone give me a short code in F# sharp for this calculation?

[image]

This is what I have so far, but I'm not convinced it's the best way:

```
let area a b c = 
  let s = sqrt((a + b + c) / 2) 
  sqrt(s * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c))
```

Comment: No, not homework. Trying myself, but I'm not sure that this ist the best solution.

Comment: `code`let area a b c = 
 let s = sqrt((a + b + c) / 2)
 sqrt(s * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c));`code`

Comment: You're almost correct. Remove `sqrt` when calculating `s`: `let area a b c = let s = (a + b + c) / 2.0 in sqrt(s * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c))`

Comment: You'd have got a better response (i.e. not closed) if you'd shown what you'd tried in your question, otherwise it does read a bit like homework or 'give me teh codez'

Comment: Since the question has been edited to add some code, it should be reopened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you're trying to apply different formulas depending on the type of triangle you have. If you have three sides you use [Heron's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula), if you have one side you're assuming the triangle is equilateral, if you have two sides you're assuming the triangle is right and the two sides are the catheti.
If I interpreted correctly, I would define a discriminated union, like this:

```
type Triangle =
| Generic of float * float * float
| Equilateral of float
| Right of float * float

let area (t : Triangle) : float = 
  match t with 
  | Generic (a, b, c) -> let s = (a + b + c) / 2. 
                         sqrt(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c))
  | Equilateral a     -> sqrt(3.) * (a ** 2.) / 4.
  | Right (a, b)      -> (a * b) / 2.

// testing
let triangles = [Generic (2., 3., 4.); Equilateral 2.; Right (2., 3.)] 

triangles |>
List.iter (fun t -> Console.WriteLine(area t))
```

Answer (score 3):

Just the translation of those formulas?
Should be something like this:

```
let area  a = (a **  2. / 4.) * sqrt 3.

let area' a b = a * b / 2.

let area'' a b c = 
    let s = (a + b + c) / 2.
    sqrt(s * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c))
```

Comment: Thank you very much Gustavo. That is quit near to my solution.